# PHP multidimensional to flat array (changing key->value)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is a problem that I come across frequently when using PHP to query mysql data, and I would like to know if there is a more efficient solution. When I only need two columns of data, for instance the columns 'id' and 'price', I prefer this 'flat' format:

```
array(
    id 1 => price 1,
    id 2 => price 2,
    id 3 => price 3,
    ...
);
```

or in json:

```
[{"id 1":"price 1"},{"id 2":"price 2"},{"id 3":"price 3"}, ...]
```

And my usual solution is to loop twice, like so:

```
require_once('server/connection.php');
$info = mysql_query("SELECT id, price FROM table");  

$array1 = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($info)) {
    $array1[] = array(
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'price' => $row['price']
    );
}
mysql_close($con);

$array2 = array();
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $array2[$key][$value['id']] = $value['price'];
}

print json_encode($array2);
```

which does work, but I think this code is too lengthy for its purpose, and there should be a better way -- so that I only have to loop one array. Any suggestions?

Comment: Second loop: you are rather making a two dimensional array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your loop to this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($info)) {
    $array1[] = array(
        'id '.$row['id'] => 'price '.$row['price']
    );
}

print json_encode($array1);
```

Comment: Thank you, this was much simpler than I thought!

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($info)) {
    $result[$row['id']] = $row['price'];
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once('server/connection.php');
$info = mysql_query("SELECT id, price FROM table");  

$array1 = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($info))
    $array1[$row['id']] = $row['price'];
mysql_close($con);

print json_encode($array1);
```

NOTE: your $array2 is a two dimensional array. If it works for you, you need to change your javascript code to handle following flat format i.e. the above code produce

```
[{"id 1":"price 1"},{"id 2":"price 2"},{"id 3":"price 3"}, ...]
```

Comment: This works well too. Thank you for pointing out that it's a two dimensional array.